# Installing PDO driver for MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to install PDO driver for MySQL but have no idea how to.

Comment: Look in the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php PHP.net is in fact one of the best documentation sites I've ever seen - it may not look great, but it works fine.

Comment: If you cant handle an install that isn't wizard driven - i.e. One click, then I am not sure you should be exploring using PHP. The PHP site is a valuable resource, and is actually one of the better laid out websites on the internet.

Comment: http://php.net/ haven't got the best looks, especially in this Web 2.0 era, but... Doh! How dare you saying it's poorly managed? One of the best sites out there, and documentation/manual part is just perfect!

Comment: it's your question which very ugly and poorly managed. Not even platform specified!

Comment: If you're not willing to use one of the easiest and best documentation sites there is (php.net) then you shouldn't be programming or doing anything technical. Coming to StackOverflow because you can't use www.google.com is not a valid reason to ask a question.

Comment: Bash php for its lack of threading, switched arguments between functions, or even its ability for beginners to make a mess out of the simplest tasks. But don't bash php.net. It is a shining marvel of technical documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find this [PHP PDO tutorial](https://phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html) helpful.

Comment: It does not cover the installation of the mySQL PDO driver.

Comment: You have to do this manually and edit your copy of php.ini to make sure the pdo extension is installed. You really do need to read the manual though.

Comment: Totally useless answer as to the wording on the question.

Comment: Now this question has been closed I can't submit a new answer, but if you're trying to get mysql and php to play nice on Ubuntu via PDO, the "php5-mysql" package is what you need.

Comment: this link not works.. please replace with new one!!

Comment: This is why you're not supposed to add links... links expire, go bad, and now this question/answer is unhelpful.

Answer (score -1):

You should have framed the question better. Mention what version of PHP you are working with and what database are you trying to talk to?? with PHP 5.1.0 you already have PDO libraries, it depends on what database you are working with to determine the drivers you need.